# Is there a definitive order to perform data compression and encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, compression

I have a requirement stating that data compression and encryption should be performed.

However, I have doubts relating to which step should be performed first in order to optimize compression rate and execution time. How can I choose which step to perform first and the compression and encryption approach to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would strongly *expect* an "encrypt then compress" approach to give you almost no compression. Encrypted data shouldn't have any discernable patterns in it, which is basically what compression relies on.

Compress then encrypt.

As for *which* kind of encryption and compression to use - that entirely depends on your context, which you haven't given any information about. Heck, you may find that your data isn't compressible in the first place.

Comment: thanks jon. its for data archiving for database. huge data will be archived. it needs to be encrypted and compressed

Comment: "huge data" is still very vague. It could compress well or badly. It could be that the existing backup facilities of the database will already compress, and possibly even encrypt as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the usual order of doing things is first compress, then encrypt. Good encryption algorithms are rather CPU expensive, so it's better to reduce the size of data first before encrypting.

Answer (score 2):

First you would be performing compression. You can use 7zip libraries for doing that. It does the encryption too, I think AES encryption.

Comment: I have used it, pretty easy to use and quite effective.